# Is there a way to convert memory adress string to little endian input?

Tags: python, pwntools

this thing could easily be solves by writing a function that builds the string that I want.
But it would be a bit nicer, and a bit more concise if there is something that I can just import and use, it seems lik there should be.
I have a python script that uses python pwntools.

It reads a memory leak from a executable that consists of a string that basically just looks like this:

```
0x80491d6
```

and I need to inject it back into the program in little endian form, so like this:

```
\xd6\x91\x04\x08
```

So that is basically just what I need to do, reverse all the chars in pairs of two.

Does anyone know of a resource that does this? perhaps in pwntools, that I am quite new to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3` itself is sufficent for that task

```
address = 0x80491d6
little = address.to_bytes(length=4,byteorder="little")
print(little)
```

output

```
b'\xd6\x91\x04\x08'
```

Disclaimer: [`.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) requires `python3.2` or newer

Comment: Thanks a lot, theres only one thing thats still annoying me though. It should be pretty simple. Since I am getting the address as a string, I need to convert it to int, so doing something like  ` address = int("0x80491d6") ` which doesnt parse. What can I do to parse this properly?

Comment: @Grazosi `int("0x80491d6",base=16)`